# Make a coil in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am looking to make a coil in three.js.  Something that can be used to move things, like in a vending machine.  I'm not sure though how to go about doing this because it doesn't seem to fit any of the existing meshes or geometries.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to create a mesh outside three.js, for example, in 3d studio max, or maya, and then import them to three.js.

[example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl)

Comment: Will it interact with other objects in the scene?

Comment: no, no objects really interact with eachother unless there is a physics framework or something running allongside three.js

Comment: im using physi.js. I'm kinda stuck as to how to draw a spring in three.js.  Once I have that I think I can get it to work with physi.js though.

Answer (score 0):

i would try the following...

1. create an array of points that describe the helix (check wikipedia for the formulae)
2. create a curve from points ( THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points) )
3. If you want a circular cross section use THREE.TubeGeometry and pass it your curve
4. if you want a non circular cross section, create a new THREE.Shape with the cross section
5. use THREE.ExtrudeGeometry and pass your shape and curve to it

just a guess hope it helps